# Create Matched Samples Based on Age and Gender in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame including 20 diagnosed and 60 undiagnosed participants. I want to create matched samples for diagnosis, based on age and gender. In other words, I want r to choose 20 participants from the undiagnosed group who are similar to the diagnosed group in terms of age and gender.

My diagnosed group consisted of females largely, but it is not the case for undiagnosed.
This is what I tried with the "MatchIt" package:

```
m.out <- matchit(as.factor(diagnosis) ~ age + gender, data = mydf,
                  method = "nearest", distance = "glm")
matched_samples <- match.data(m.out)
```

then it gave me two groups based on diagnosis thankfully, however it did something weird for gender:

```
#number of participants per group
    diagnosis  n freq 
      <chr> <int> <chr>
    yes       20 50%  
    no        20 50% 

#gender distribution across the diagnosis

diagnosis   gender  n 
  <chr>    <chr>  <int> 
1 yes      male     6 
2 yes      female  14
3 no       male    20
```

It chose only the males for the nondiagnosed group, although I have enough female participants. Why might this be the case?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `matchit()` does 1:1 matching on the propensity score. What you probably want is exact matching on gender and nearest neighbor matching on age. Try this:

```
m.out <- matchit(as.factor(diagnosis) ~ age, data = mydf,
                 method = "nearest", exact = ~gender,
                 distance = "euclidean")
matched_samples <- match.data(m.out)
```

This will give you pairs of units with identical genders who are closely matched on age.

If exact matching is not possible, then you have to accept some imbalance in gender. You can try other matching methods (e.g., optimal matching, cardinality matching) and different distance measures (e.g., Mahalanobis distance, robust Mahalanobis distance) to find the one that gives you the balance you want.

Comment: thank you so much, it has worked. It gave me the closest age and exact gender match. Can I ask a question, some of the participants have so many unanswered questions and r included those participants in the match too. Is there any way I can tell R to consider the amount of NAs while choosing participants? Or I should just arrange my sample accordingly before matching in order to omit participants who have too many NAs.

Comment: You can always create a variable that is the number of `NA`s. Not sure what you'd do with that other than subset the data to remove cases with too many `NA`s. Note that you can barely do anything with a sample of 40 people, and dropping even more of them because they have missing values will make your results even more fragile.